# Why increasing spark.sql.shuffle.partitions will cause FetchFailedException

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I meet a FetchFailedException when join to table while setting spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 2700

But run successfully when  setting spark.sql.shuffle.partitions = 500 .

As I know increasing shuffle.partitions will decrease data in every task when shuffle read..

Am I miss something?

**Exception**:

```
FetchFailed(BlockManagerId(699, nfjd-hadoop02-node120.jpushoa.com, 7337, None), shuffleId=4, mapId=59, reduceId=1140, message=
org.apache.spark.shuffle.FetchFailedException: failed to allocate 16777216 byte(s) of direct memory (used: 2147483648, max: 2147483648)
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.throwFetchFailedException(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:554)
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:485)
at org.apache.spark.storage.ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.next(ShuffleBlockFetcherIterator.scala:64)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.nextCur(Iterator.scala:435)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$12.hasNext(Iterator.scala:441)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:31)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:37)
at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:409)
at org.apache.spark.sql.catalyst.expressions.GeneratedClass$GeneratedIteratorForCode
```

**Config**:

```
spark.executor.cores = 1
spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors = 800
```

Comment: Which resource manager are you using? It looks like you may be running out of resources by instantiating more workers in parallel, than your underlying system (or ulimits?) allows. I assume the memory limitation comes from either the VM, or the ulimit. If you reduce maxExecutors, is the issue resolved?

Comment: @RickMoritz I am using yarn as my resource manager  , Is it different between 500 task? and 2700 tasks?  The max Parallelism is according to  spark.dynamicAllocation.maxExecutors and spark.executor.cores (in my cases , the max parallelism will be 800)

Answer (score 0):

After Reading the code of shuffleFetch .

The problem I meet is the real block from ShuffleMapTask is too large to fetch into memory once, and the block size from driver is a average block size If my shuffle partitions more than 2000(according to spark.shuffle.minNumPartitionsToHighlyCompress ) which will be  smaller then real size when having skew data.